# Expected RBRACE error in WordPress style.css

Tags: html, css, grid

I am using WordPress 5.3.1 and I am getting the issue in css while creating a grid.

> Expected RBRACE

**Screenshot**

[image]

This is the code I am using. It's working on local server but getting the issue on WordPress style.css

```
.cp-seeWrapper ul {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
      grid-gap: 10px;
    }
```

Would you help me out with a solution?

Comment: Please check your css again. There should an error of  "right curly bracket".

Comment: @RevtiShah, I checked again the same issue, If I remove this css then the error goes off if add then showing an error. The issue is with this css grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);

Comment: Use this grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;

Comment: @RevtiShah, Same issue.

Comment: Now there should be an another issue. Because grid template column's css is proper.

Comment: remove that line and run your project.

Comment: Yes, I remove that live and css working but if I add then the same issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204389/discussion-between-revti-shah-and-naren-verma).

Answer (score -1):

Here is the code. Hope it will help you. If any changes please let me know.Use **grid: 50% 50% / repeat(2, 50%);**. It solves your problem.

https://jsfiddle.net/bny5eq03/2/

```css
.exclusive-content ul{
  display: grid;
  grid: 50% 50% / repeat(2, 50%);
  justify-content: center;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="exclusive-content">
  <ul>
    <li>Hello</li>
    <li>Hello</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Give me some time to check this

Comment: But an fr unit takes the gap into account, this code does not. If you make a column gap larger you will see scroll bars. This is more likely just the linter being used not recognizing the fr units, the WordPress customizer on older versions of WP has this issue.